# Get body request parameters using express in V2 Dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm migrating my Google Action from v1 => v2 using an express app, and in the past, I've been able to get url params & initialize my action map like this:

```
// INITIALIZE EXPRESS APPLICATION & ENDPOINTS
app.use(bodyParser.json({strict: false}));

// POST [TYPE] [PLATFORM] [PUBLISHER] PARAMS => PASS TO FULFILLMENT
app.post('/:platform/:type/:publisher', function(req, res) {
  debugRequest(req);
  console.log(`SENDING TO ${TYPE} => ${PLATFORM} => ${PUBLISHER} FULFILLMENT`);
  fulfillment.fulfillment(req, res);
});
```

```

With v2, instead of using a `.post` route with express, I just need to use `.use` e.g. `express().use(bodyParser.json(), app)`. However, I don't understand how to get the body params (req/res) using this method [still kind of a node newbie] from body parser.

I need the full URL path (type, platform, publisher) from the request in order to fulfill some app logic later on, within various intents.

If someone has a more built out express / v2 Dialogflow example, that'd be very helpful. I have all this working with v1, but times are a changing!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get this data now with the new Framework Metadata feature added in `2.2.0`. See this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/156#issuecomment-399580513) for more details.

An object containing framework metadata is now present as the 2nd parameter in the middleware function.

Now you can do something like:

```es6
app.middleware((conv, framework) => {
  if (framework.express) {
    conv.expressParams = framework.express.request.expressParams;
  }
});

app.intent('some intent', conv => {
  conv.ask(`Params sent was ${JSON.stringify(conv.expressParams)}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From a similar question in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/issues/128):

> You can retrieve the raw JSON data from `conv.request` for the core Actions on Google data and `conv.body` for the entire JSON body.

Comment: Yes, `conv.request` & `conv.body` do contain a lot of data, but not the full URL / path. 

for example, I should be able to get the path params /:type / :platform, etc. but I don't see those keys anywhere in the conv objects